# Sequence starts with 1 after reaching MAXVALUE even STARTWITH 100 specified

Tags: oracle, sequence, cycle

I've come across a very weird Oracle sequence behavior. I have the following Sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ1 INCREMENT BY 10 START WITH 100 MAXVALUE 200 CYCLE NOCACHE;
```

Here's an excerpt from "OCA/OCP Oracle Database 11g All-in-One Exam Guide":

> CYCLE Controls the behavior on reaching MAXVALUE or MINVALUE. The
>   default behavior is to give an error, but if CYCLE is specified the
>   sequence will return to its starting point and repeat.

From this I infer that after reaching the MAXVALUE of 200, I'll get 100, as the starting point is 100. But surprisingly I get one. Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at the following excerpt from [document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm):

> Specify `CYCLE` to indicate that the sequence continues to generate
>   values after reaching either its maximum or minimum value. After an
>   ascending sequence reaches its maximum value, it generates its minimum
>   value. After a descending sequence reaches its minimum, it generates
>   its maximum value.

It means that `START WITH` value is not enough in your case, so **both** `MINVALUE` and `MAXVALUE` should be settled. Without given `MINVALUE`, cycle will start from number 1.

Comment: That really explains the behavior. It clearly indicates that `it generates its minimum value`. So the book I was referring had to be careful when choosing words. In fact that book is also by Oracle and there's no word about starting with the minimum value.

Comment: The same can go to international books that are translated by _translators_ and not by _database specialists_

Answer (score 4):

When your sequence cycles, it starts again at the `MINVALUE` of the sequence.  That defaults to 1 if you don't specify a value.  If you wanted the sequence to start again at 100, you'd need to specify a `MINVALUE` of 100.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the oracle document on this, and it was written like 'it will start with 100' in their case 1000

Creating a Sequence: Example
The following statement creates the sequence customers_seq in the sample schema oe. This sequence could be used to provide customer ID numbers when rows are added to the customers table.

CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq
 START WITH     1000
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

The first reference to customers_seq.nextval returns 1000. The second returns 1001. Each subsequent reference will return a value 1 greater than the previous reference.